# Why is setStreamVolume not working for Vivo Android devices running Android 12?

Tags: android, android-audiomanager, android-12

AudioManager setStreamVolume api is not setting volume for Vivo devices running android 12 and above

I am trying the below code to set the stream volume of the device :
Here streamType value is always 0 or 1 as I am using a video call/normal.
Here convertedIndex ranges from 1 to 10.
Flags i have tried different including AudioManager.STREAM_VOICECALL,AudioManager.STREAM_SYSTEM etc. Right now set as 0 as well. But still volume is not getting set. Made a check for isVolumeFixed before setting.
audioManager?.setStreamVolume(streamType, convertedIndex, 0).
Apart from setStreamVolume, tried below apis as well :
adjustVolume
adjustStreamVolume
adjustSuggestedStreamVolume
setVolumeIndexForAttributes

But none of the apis set volume for Vivo android devices. What could be the possible reason.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community setStreamVolume is not setting volume for vivo devices running android 12 or higher,whereas it works for other devices running android 12 and higher

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify your system sound settings in developers option and try it again after rebooting the system .

Comment: This is not helpful. Users cannot do this stuff right. Please share valid points